# Displaying certain post formats on a template page returns NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, post-format

I have created a template page where I only want to show gallery and image post formats with the query below. The problem is that I don't get anything to show and when I try to `var_dump()` I get NULL.

```
$args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-image', 'post-format-gallery' ),
            ),
        )
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

            if( $loop->have_posts() ):

                //echo '<div class="page-limit" data-page="/">';

                while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();

                    var_dump(the_post());

                endwhile;

                //echo '</div>';

            endif;

    wp_reset_query();

        ?>
```

Do i have to update the taxonomies for my post formats or what? And if I have to do that how would I do it?
One more thing, I want to display the current post format from my template page, i.e. `content-image.php`, `content-gallery.php`...

Comment: `the_post` does not return anything, so what output did you expect? All this does is call the method of the same name of WP_Query, and the purpose of that method is to, quote documentation, _"advance onto the next post, and set the global $post variable."_

Comment: I solved this with `get_posts()`